# Python upload file through AWS api gateway to s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests

I have an API on AWS for uploading files to s3. For now, I use this method for uploading files. My problem is that it can't handle big files and binary files are allot bigger when they arrive at s3 and can't be read again. But small text files work's great with this method. My question is if someone knows a better way to handle **large** file uploads in Python than the method below.

```
url = API_URL + '/archive/store/' + fileUploadPath
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'X-API-KEY': apiKey,
    'X-USER-ID': userID,
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
}
file.seek(0)
files = file.read()
return requests.request("PUT", url, data=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What errors do you get when trying a large file?

Comment: I get an error on the client side that the request is too big.

Comment: Assuming your files exceed the 5GB limit, you'll need to do a [multipart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)

Comment: I thought I needed to add the content-type in the headers. So I don't need that?

Comment: When I try to upload a zip file on 18MB I get the following error, `HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes.` and HTTP status code 413

Comment: No, content-type isn't necessary. The API [**does** require you to include the `content-length` header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html#RESTObjectPUT-requests). This may be what's causing the issue.

Comment: I have added the content-length but I still have the same issue for binary files. for example, I upload a jpg on 319kB and on S3 it is 566kB. But normal text files is the same after upload.

Comment: Post more of your code. Are you assigning file as `file = open('filename.jpg', 'rb')`?

Comment: The file is an uploaded file to Django from a Django Form `fileToUpload = forms.FileField(label='File', widget=CustomFileInput())` Can it be Django that can't handle binary files.

Comment: Do you use AWS Lambda or your own backend service to upload the files to S3?

Comment: I use a direct S3 integration with AWS API Gateway.

Comment: Same problem happened with me. What should I do now? I create API gateway + AWS Lambda and save file to S3. but now if I send more than 10MB file it gives error. then how should I do now?